# Talend open studio for Data Integration: Today's date and automation

Tags: date, automation, talend

`I am currently trying to extract from a database A (Oracle) different ID to db B (MySQL).`

`I use Talend`. However the purpose is to automate this process so that newcomers to database `A can be added to db B automatically.`

I would need to automate the job I have built. **I have no idea how to do that using talend.** Moreover, I would like to do the automation using a condition `variable_date_db_A < 'today's date' however I don't know how to "access" today's date on talend ...`

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You can find many tutorials on google on how to automate Talend jobs, here's one : https://www.upcurvecloud.com/blog/sugarcrm/automating-talend-jobs-to-transfer-data/  
in order to use today's date, you can filter your oracle query: where myDate < SYSDATE

Answer (score 0):

This can be used in a `tMap` or `tJavaRow` to get the current date:

```
TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TalendDate.getCurrentDate())
```

Regarding automation there are two basic methods that I can point out to you:

1. if you have the paid version then it comes with a job scheduler (Talend Administration Console)
2. otherwise in the free version (Talend Open Studio), you can compile an executable and run it in any scheduler (Windows scheduler for free, or any enterprise scheduler your organization may be utilizing).

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to "access" today's date on talend.

To access today's date in Talend you can use Java's Date method or by using methods/ routines given by Talend itself i.e. `TalendDate.getCurrentDate();`

If you want to format the date, then you can use `TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd", TalendDate.getCurrentDate());`

As you want to compare the dates, then it's better to store the date in `Date` Type format, so that you may use `TalendDate.compareDate(Date date1, Date date2);` inbuilt function.

As you want to insert only newly created data, then you can use `inner join - reject` in tmap. So that you will insert those data which is not present in the system.

> I would need to automate the job I have built

1. If you are using Talend Enterprise version, then you can schedule it using TAC (Talend Administration Console).
2. If you are using Open Studio Community version, then create an executable build, by right-clicking on the job from the repository and `build job` and create `Standalone Job. And you can schedule it, using Windows scheduler or using cron in linux.